# Nonprincipal lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\Lambda$ be a $J$-module generated by the elements $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ which are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, $v_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$.

It is said that in case $J$ is not a PID (for example, in case $J=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$), $\Lambda$ may not be a free $J$-module.

**Can someone explain how this can be true?**

The question comes from the book: J.H. Conway, N.J.A. Sloane "Sphere packings, Lattices and Groups", 1988; p. 53

---

Slightly edited excerpt:

> [image]